# React Native ios 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I got a problem with my app.

When I try to build it on **Android Studio** everything works fine but when I try to build it on **Xcode** I got an error and the build fails.

The reason seems to come from AirMaps:

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue

`'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h'` file not found

```
AIRGoogleMapUrlTile.h
```

It's strange because it worked fine until now and I can't find why.

I'm using:

```
- "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
- "react-native": "0.43.3",
- "react-native-maps": "^0.21.0"
```

and here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Situaction' do
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'

  pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
        end
    end
    if target.name == "React"
        target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

Can you help me please,

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
here are the header search paths.
[Header Search Paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7CRo.png)

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow! Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and adjust your question. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so I just found a solution that worked :

> add pod Google-Maps-iOS-Utils in the podfile
>   remove AirMaps.xcodeproj from Libraries
>   remove libAirMap.a from Link Binary with Libraries

But now i got a new problem: the map appears but now i can't use fitToCoordinates because an error occur:

```
Unknown argument type 'AIRMapCoordinatesArray' in method - [AIRGoogleMapManager fitToCoordinates:coordinates:edgePadding:animated: ). Extend RCTConvert to support this type.
```

when i take a look to the debugger it tells me:

```
Warning: Native component for "AIRMap" does not exist
```

(more info in the [react-native-maps issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/2339) I reported)

Edit:
I added the AirMaps folder in my project and everything seems to work fine

Comment: What do you mean by adding "AirMaps" folder in a project? Can you tell exactly how you did it?

Comment: Could you provide more context to your answer?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using React Native 0.60 and higher, add the following to your `Podfile` above the `use_native_modules!` function and run `pod install` in the ios folder:

```
  # React Native Maps dependencies
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
```

[visit the documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#enabling-google-maps-on-ios-react-native-all-versions)

Answer (score 0):

```
target 'YourApp' do
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  pod 'yoga', path: "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec"
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'BatchedBridge'
  ]

  pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path

  pod 'GoogleMaps'  # Remove this line if you don't want to support Google Maps on iOS
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path  # Remove this line if you don't want to support Google Maps on iOS
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I just tried your pod file, I had to remove BatchedBridge because it wasn't in my ReactCommon folder, replace 'yoga' by 'Yoga' and I added Fabrics and Crashlytics to make it run. But in the end I still have the same problem...  I added the header search paths if it can help you.

Comment: I just now created a react-native project with 0.43.3 version and tried react-native-maps with this pod file and changes you said, it is building without any error. Did you use react-native-link for maps?

Comment: in the package.json file i have "react-native-map-link": "^1.1.3" is this what you mean ?

Comment: I don't think so, i'm working on an app made by someone else so i don't really know what has been done. do you want me to run this command ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I updated AirMaps's Framework Search Paths to `$(PROJECT_DIR) (recursive)` and `$(inherited) (recursive)` works for me.

[image]

[image]

I am not sure that it will work for you. Please give me feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Native 0.65 and higher, add the following to your Podfile and run pod install :

React Native Maps dependencies

```
 rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
```

*Note : also do check in AppDelegate.m

`#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h> [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@“YOUR_API_KEY”];`

And if you see white screen on iOS device:

1. do check with your API key
2. Enable Maps SDK for iOS from your GCP console.